# Recreating a website's background

Tags: css, background, gradient

So, my question is about how the background that's on http://www.origin.com/en-us/store/ ?
Ive figured out the 4x4 transparency background with a repeat in CSS3. It still does not look right. It looks like there's a transparent linear gradient over the top of it to kind of smooth it out. Any help or ideas? I've searched for quite awhile with no positive results. So far I can do two backgrounds at once but they do not look anything close to what I need.
Thank you for your help! I'm rather new to web programming.
Best Regards,
Fallow

Answer (score 0):

just open your dev-tools (such as chrome dev tools) and inspect the dom?

its a background-image (#wrapper) and `background: #959595;` (#outer-wrapper)